# How disable delete button when mysql value data is used on another table? C#

Tags: c#, events

how i can **disable Delete Button** when i use "**mouse click event**" on datagridview category when a value form category is used in medicine table, so if i click datagrid row with IDC value is 1 or 2 tthen Delete Button is **disable** because a value used in medicine table, but when click datagrid row with IDC is 3 then Delete Button is **Enable** .

example I have 2 tables in my database apotek

```
Table : Medicine
IDB Name IDC
1   A      1
2   B      2

Table : Category
IDC Category
1   AA      
2   BB      
3   CC
```

this is my example code

```
bool c = true;
    MySqlConnection koneksi = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=apotek;User Id=root;password=''");




private void DataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from medicine", koneksi);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            koneksi.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                if (myReader[1].ToString()==mydatagrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                {
                    c= true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (c== true)
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                button2.Enabled = true;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        koneksi.Close();
```

But when i run, its only disable button when i click on first row.... Not row with IDC is 3

Thank You

Comment: Can you please show us your code? A [mcve] would be fantastic?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this site is not meant to have others write code for you. Revise your question to state what you are confused about, what you have tried and example code of what you have done in order to have the StackOverflow community provide you with support in answering your question. Best of luck!

Comment: Use the mouse click event and disable the button.

Comment: @JeremyThompson that my code *edited..

Comment: @Chris Catigani yeah but how, i cant

Comment: Have you tried to debug through your code?

Comment: @programmer444 yes, but only disable when i click on first row with IDC is 1 but not disable when i click on second row. Thats all i wanna disable in row have relation between medicine table and category table

Comment: Please provide us the data from the datagrid and what values are you getting from "mydatagrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();". Maybe you have to use something like described here: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html